# Shell script for list of users by groups

Tags: users, scripts, groups

I want to write a shell script that generates a list of users. for each user display the username and ID and all groups the user is a member of

it means like GROUPS command but for all users and with their id
I used cat -d: -f1,3 /etc/passwd to show the users with their id but I don't know how can I use the groups for each line

would you please help me to write this script
thanks

Comment: example :" Ubuntu:1000: ubuntu adm dialout cdrom plugdv lpadmin admin "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this script:

```
#! /bin/bash
#
for i in $(cat /etc/passwd  | cut -d: -f1); do
   echo -n $i ": "
   grep $i /etc/group | cut -d: -f1 | tr "\n" " "
   echo
done
```

It will list all users in the system (included system) and print the list of groups near them. With a trivial modification you can print the numeric id too.

Comment: example :" Ubuntu:1000: ubuntu adm dialout cdrom plugdv lpadmin admin "

Comment: ShowUserNGroups now in ~/bin directory! 
I'm going to analyse it more carefully in the morning when I'm not so "tired".  ;) (upvoted too!)